# How do you post a like link without using Like Button plugin

Tags: facebook-like

How do you post a like link without using Like Button plugin? and not shared a link and then like it.
I need a like posted after user confirm she want to post it to fb or not.
Is there a way?or I should shared a link and the like it?

Comment: I think this is not the idea or concept and sounds like cheating.

Comment: there are similar like/unlike function on my website, because not all of my user have fb, so user can choose to post it to their fb or not. thats why I need post a like link after user confirmed it

Comment: ok, understood. You might have to look at the Facebook API or just add two buttons. Most pages have multiple buttons.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is very simple.  You can use the graph API to post to a user's feed the link.  The API returns the ID of the post you just made.  Then you can call the graph API to like that ID.